# Partial recursive function and Turing machine

Tags: terminology, turing-machines, recursion

The wikipedia article about [primitive recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) states that

> An equivalent definition states that a partial recursive function is one that can be computed by a Turing machine.

My question is how one can write down formally this definition?

Comment: If you are interested in the details, I suggest you get an introductory textbook on the matter.

Comment: [This answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/31983/43824) is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You first define what a *partial recursive function* is, and then what a Turing machine is.  Then you show that for every set (problem), there is a Turing machine computing it if and only if it is definable by a partial recursive function.

What you actually would do is to simulate a Turing machine by a partial recursive function and vice versa.  Right to left is simple, left to right takes some work.  You must define an encoding of the machine states (use of e.g. powers of prime numbers), the transition function, a *configuration* of a machine (i.e., what is currently on the tape, where is the head, and in which state is the machine) etc.