# What is a partially computable function?

Tags: terminology, computability

In the book *Computability, Complexity, and Languages*, Martin Davis writes in chapter two:

> A partial function is said to be partially computable  if it is computed by some program.

and also

> A function is said to be computable if it is both partially computable and total.

From the first definition, a partially computable function must be a *partial function*, but from the second definition a computable function must be partially computable and total which is a contradiction, because a function is partially computable if it is partial and a partial function can not be total at the same time!

Comment: Note that [other authors](https://books.google.com/books?id=AHvoluqx7uoC&pg=PA128) are very allergic to the term "partial**ly** computable function" precisely because it's like saying something is a "partially function".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The definition of *partial function* doesn't exclude the possibility that the function is total. On the contrary, every total function is a fortiori a partial function. Perhaps the terminology is unfortunate.

A *function* from $D$ to $R$ is a subset $f$ of $D \times R$ such that for all $d \in D$ there exists a unique $r \in R$ (denoted $f(d)$) such that $(d,r) \in f$. The *domain* of $f$ is $\operatorname{dom} f = D$.

A *partial function* from $D$ to $R$, where $\bot \notin R$, is a function $f$ from $D$ to $R \cup \{\bot\}$. When $f(d) = \bot$, we say that $f$ is *undefined* at $d$. The *domain* of $f$ is $\operatorname{dom} f = \{d \in D : f(d) \neq \bot\}$. If $\operatorname{dom} f = D$ then $f$ is *total*. For every partial function $f$, $f|_{\operatorname{dom} f}$ is a total function.

As you can see, a partial function is a function which can be undefined for some of the inputs; a total function is a partial function which happens to be defined everywhere.

Now regarding computability. Every program computes some partial function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$; if the program doesn't halt on some input $x$, then $f$ is undefined on $x$, in other words, $f(x) = \bot$. A computable function is one computed by an algorithm which always halts.

Comment: Here is a very important note that you pointed out: **every total function is a fortiori a partial function** Then how can you interpret the second definition of my question? *A function is said to be computable if it is both partially computable and total.*

Comment: See the last paragraph in my edited answer. Every program computes some partial function, which is undefined on inputs on which it doesn't halt. A computable function is a total function which is computed by some program. By definition, this program must always halt.

Comment: As a side note, it's a common confusion to think you can take a total computable function, restrict it to an arbitrary sub-domain and get a partial computable function. More on that at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1133168/173347 Some authors prefer to say "computable partial function" instead because of this issue, but there are potential confusions with that terminology choice too.